# Bulk Update stored procedure with user input (WITHOUT A DATATABLE)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Can I perform a bulk update using a stored procedure that sends data to a temp table from user input which is not in a datatable.

If I have a foreach loop that takes user input such as values from a checkboxlist and text boxes what I want to know is how to parameterize those separate values in my stored procedure or if I can do it in my code. I cannot use table-valued parameters since I'm using a version of SQL that does not support it.

```
 conn.Open();

 foreach(ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
 {
    if(item.Selected)
    {
        //handling parameters in loop.
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Update_Account_Table";
        cmd.Parameters["@SeqNum"].Value = amount.Text;
        cmd.Parameters["@SeqDate"].Value = DateTime.ParseExact(datepicker.Text, "mmddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        cmd.Parameters["@Account_ID"].CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    conn.Close();
 }
```

Stored procedure

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable
(
    SeqNum int,
    SeqDate datetime,
    Account_ID varchar(2)
);  

CREATE PROCEDURE [ACCOUNTTABLE_UPDATE]
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN
        UPDATE AccountTable
        SET SeqNum = t.SeqNum, SeqDate = t.SeqDate
        FROM AccountTable AT
        INNER JOIN TempTable t ON AT.AccountID = t.AccountID
    END
```

Comment: I had done something similar previously using XML parameters. You can read up http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1017781-391-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This uses a dynamic table name in stored procedure, and sets value based on incoming parameter. You could use code below instead of temp table, or use parameters @seqnum, @SeqDate, @AcctID in place of @Stats_Value below:

```
USE [EODData]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[erase_Stats]    Script Date: 8/23/2016 4:32:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[erase_Stats]
    @table varchar(25), @stats_value int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare @ProductsSQL nvarchar(max);
SET @ProductsSQL = 'update ' + @table + ' set stats_completed = @Stats_Value'
exec sp_executesql @ProductsSQL
END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add # before the table to make it temporary table

your should be like

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
```

will create temporary table and destroyed  after process completes